# Angular dynamic nested directive, passing a new scope to each child?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to create a nested directive in angular, which is specified by a large, possibly deeply nested config object. I'm having trouble figuring out how to get the correct scope to the correct directive.

My example plunkr is here: http://plnkr.co/edit/AJVaSk2GSxIJvZx3B6UX?p=preview

I think that I could copy the current child config into an attribute on each child and get that via the scope attribute of the directive definition, but that seems a little crazy - it could be huge, and might need to be escaped.

Is there a better way to do this, or something else I've completely missed? (Or another SO question that answers this that I've missed...)

Very much obliged.

**Edit from comment for clarification**

I'm trying to get each directive to have a scope (or even just a variable on the scope?) for each sub-object. So 'theform' directive gets the top level object, each 'theforma' directive gets the child that created it. That is, I'd have one 'theforma' directive with the object containing 'type' : 'form_a_child_1', and the other would have the object containing 'type' : 'form_a_child_2'. So they'd be "self-contained" and only really know about the object they were created with.

Ultimately, then, I'd like a submit button, and a way to gather all of the information from the dynamic form elements...but that's for another question.

Comment: I don't really understand the question... you have three directives, one that uses the other two currently and then you have a model for your controller scope that you'll use to pass along to the directives.  Each directive can have it's own scope where it only gets the data it needs to operate passed to it.  Everything you did seems to make sense I just don't understand where the problem is?

Comment: I'm trying to get each directive to have a scope (or even just a variable on the scope?) for each sub-object. So 'theform' directive gets the top level object, each 'theforma' directive gets the child that created it. That is, I'd have one 'theforma' directive with the object containing 'type' : 'form_a_child_1', and the other would have the object containing 'type' : 'form_a_child_2'. So they'd be "self-contained" and only really know about the object they were created with. Does that make more sense? Or is the question still nonsensical? :) Thanks!

Comment: No that makes sense but you're about 90% of the way there you would just want to define a scope for your directive definition object.  It's called making an isolate scope because it makes it so the directive doesn't inherit the scope from the controller it's being used in (thereby isolating it).  Check out the videos on egghead.io for some details on implementation I'll try to put together an answer in a couple of hours here.

Comment: I guess I just don't understand how to pass the isolate scope down to the child. As a big, json encoded attribute? I just noticed the "scope:true" option - is that something I should mess with? Looking forward to your answer - and I'll rewatch all the egghead.io videos. They're awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Got distracted by video games yesterday hope this wasn't terribly urgent to get resolved but I posted an answer here now.  This is probably not exactly what you want to do but should get the idea across about isolate scope.

http://plnkr.co/edit/FmpixQrBmvWJlB2wBRXW?p=preview

JS

```
// Code goes here

var app = angular.module('formtest', []);

app.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope){
  $scope.form_config = { 
      // first level children are the tabs
      children    : [ 
          {   
              type : 'form_a',
              label : 'Form A',
              children : [ 
                  {   
                      type : 'form_a_child_1',
                      label : 'Form A Child 1',
                  },  
                  {   
                      type : 'form_a_child_2',
                      label : 'Form A Child 2',
                  },  
              ]   
          },  
          {   
              type : 'form_b',
              label : 'Form B',
              children : [ 
                  {   
                      type : 'form_b_child_1',
                      label : 'Form B Child 1',
                  },  
                  {   
                      type : 'form_b_child_2',
                      label : 'Form B Child 2',
                  },  
              ]   
          },  
      ]   
  };  
})




/**
 * Should display the top level form info.
 * Form A and Form B
 */
app.directive('theform', function() {
    return {
        restrict : 'E',
        scope:{formConfig:"="},
        template : '<div>'+
                      '<div>'+
                          '<div><theforma form-a="formAData"></div>'+
                          '<div><theformb form-b="formBData"></div>'+
                      '</div>'+
                    '</div>',
        replace  : true,
        link     : function(scope, $el, $attrs) {
            //$scope.form_config = form_config;
            scope.formAData = [];
            scope.formBData = [];
            scope.$watch("formConfig", function(newVal){
              if(newVal)
              {
                for(var i=0; i<scope.formConfig.children.length; i++)
                {
                  var curElement = scope.formConfig.children[i];
                  console.log(curElement);
                  if(curElement.type == "form_a")
                    scope.formAData = curElement;
                  else
                    scope.formBData = curElement;
                }
              }
              console.log(scope.formAData);
            })

        }   
    };  
});

/**
 * I want to display the children of Form A
 */
app.directive('theforma', function() {
    return {
        restrict : 'E',
        scope : {formA : "="},
        template : '<div>'+
                        '<div ng-repeat="child in formA.children">'+
                            'Form A: {{child.label}}'+
                        '</div>' +
                   '</div>',
        replace  : true,
        link     : function(scope, $el, $attrs) {
            //console.log(scope.formA)
        }   
    };  
});

/**
 * I want to display the children of Form B
 */
app.directive('theformb', function() {
    return {
        restrict : 'E',
        scope : {formB : "="},
        template : '<div>'+
                            '<div ng-repeat="child in formB.children">'+
                                'Form B: {{child.label}}'+
                            '</div>' +
                        '</div>',
        replace  : true,
        link     : function(scope, $el, $attrs) {
            scope.children = scope.formB;
        }   
    };  
});
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.2.14" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.14/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app='formtest' ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div>
      <theform form-config="form_config"></theform>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

When it comes to isolate scope for a directive you have three options for what you put in the quotes after a property name (=, &, or @).  = makes the property two way bind, so if you pass in a Javascript object the changes are made to that object, @ will get you a string result from the expression you pass in and pass through that string, & allows you to pass a reference to a function to be executed on the original scope (that of the controller or another directive that uses it).